# BaseController ASPCore MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to implement a BaseController Action method that gets called either before or after the Action of the Controller class used to modify a View before its renders to Razor.

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseViewModel() {}
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ViewModel () : base() {}
    // Some View Methods
}

public class BaseController
{
    public BaseController();

    // here is where I want to put code to intercept the call to the 
    // AccountController when any action is performed and write to the
    // Property1  of the Base class of the ViewModel  class.
}


public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public AccountController() : base() {}

    public IActionResult About()
    { 
       return(new ViewModel());
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do what I'm trying to explain, or if its even achievable.
Could I get some feedback or recommendations?

The BaseViewModel will contains properties that are more generic to all pages like Culture, Title etc and not related to the ViewModel at all but perhaps renderded on the View.

Comment: You need to look at action filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0 to execute code before and after actions

Comment: It'd consider putting it where Matt said, but placing the behavior in a separate class instead of inheriting from a base controller. Inheritance is not the best way for multiple classes to share a behavior. It gets complicated because then if you want another "base" behavior you put it in the base class, but what if not every controller should have that other behavior? That problem is solved by preferring composition over inheritance. Inheritance is like the dark side. Once you go down that road forever will it dominate your destiny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to override OnActionExecuting:

```
// Custom Base controller.
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do whatever here...
    }
}

// Account controller.
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    // Action methods here...
}
```