# Using a Model for Partial Views in a Layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very basic Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head></head>
    
    <body>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Shared/_Menu.cshtml");}
        @{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml");}
        @{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml");}
    </body>

</html>
```

My problem is that menu, header and footer require a Model to load some sort of dynamic data which is common for all Views.

I can solve it by changing RenderPartial to RenderAction, example:

Layout:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetFooter", "Layout");}
```

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult GetFooter()
{
    FooterViewModel footerViewModel = new FooterViewModel
    {
        // do whatever code is required
    };
    
    return PartialView("/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml", footerViewModel);
}
```

But I was reading that RenderAction is a big no-no as it performs an entire cycle of MVC so what options do I have?

Comment: @Html.Partial() , allows model param

Comment: Yes but my Layout has no Model and from what I understand there is no HttpGet action linked with the Layout where I can load the dynamic data.

Comment: You could send info using ViewData['footerViewModel'] to renderpartial

Comment: And where would I place the code to fill ViewData['footerViewModel']?

Answer (score 0):

You could send info using ViewData['footerViewModel'] to renderpartial

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var footerViewModel = new FooterViewModel
     ...
    ViewData["footerViewModel"] = footerViewModel;
  
    return View();
}
```

**view**

```
<ul>
@{var m = ViewData["footerViewModel"] as FooterViewModel}

    <li>
        @m.XX
    </li>

</ul>
```

- ViewData transfers data from the Controller to View, not vice-versa.
- ViewData is derived from ViewDataDictionary which is a dictionary type.
- ViewData's life only lasts during current http request. ViewData values will be cleared if redirection occurs.
- ViewData value must be type cast before use.
- ViewBag internally inserts data into ViewData dictionary. So the key of ViewData and property of ViewBag must NOT match.

[source](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewdata-in-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: But wouldn't this mean that I have to do the ```var footerViewModel = new FooterViewModel``` coding in every controller action? That's a lot of repetitive code, ideally the footer is loaded in a centralised place.

Comment: DRY principle => use a baseController or similiar... , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396901/basecontroller-aspcore-mvc  , also you could read about  Dependency Injection

Comment: A base controller sounds like a good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: Great, please you don't forget to mark it as correct answer or create a new question if you find a distinct issue